# facebook opengraph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Question,

Can I leave the open graph url blank, but dynamically pass the url to the button and have it function properly?

The url is dyanamic and updated by ajax from user interactions on the page. So if I put a value in the og meta, it will be different than the actual page url (after user interactions).

thanks.

or by using FBML - is there any issue updating the fb:like button dynamically like:

```
<script>
var fb_ps_page = window.location.href;
document.write('<fb:like href=" '+ fb_ps_page +'" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot dynamically update the link for the like button.  You will have to remove it from the DOM and reinsert it.  Then call FB.XFBML.parse() to get facebook to render their iframe with the new url.

Comment: right - but what about opengraph? I can't adjust meta tags on the fly - so do I have to go a non opengraph solution?

Comment: Meta tags are read by the linter and those are cached for 24 hours at a time.

Comment: ok. How about for dynamically generated pages with static urls. Can I dynamically pass the url to the iframe src using js?

Comment: You should program the dynamically generated content to also have canonical URLs so the linter can access it.  So you would have example.com/page.php?pageid=123 for the URL that facebook could use to get to the content someone would navigate to using AJAX from just example.com/page.php. **Canonical** is the important part.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding why I can't leave the opengraph url meta blank, and update the iframe src url on the fly.

Comment: If it works, then do it.  I have serious doubts that it will work that way.  How hard is it to remove something from the DOM?  `$("#mydiv").empty();`  How hard is it to then reinsert your like button code back into the DOM `$("#mydiv").html(html);`?  And how hard is it to call `FB.XFBML.parse()`?  But as I said, if changing the url on the iframe src works for you, then go for it

Comment: My response is still same. If you want to change the url, change it by removing it from the DOM then reinserting it and reparsing it.  Or use your technique if you're so sure it works well for you.  BTW, FBML is deprecated and FBML != XFBML.